# Count the individual values within the arrays stored in a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a simple example to set the stage:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example_series = pd.Series([np.arange(5), 
                            np.arange(15), 
                            np.arange(12), 
                            np.arange(7), 
                            np.arange(3)])
print example_series

0                                      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
2               [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
3                                [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
4                                            [0, 1, 2]
```

I've got a pandas Series (example_series) that contains a bunch of arrays. I'm trying to count the number of instances each number appears in the series. So, I'm hoping to return something that looks like:

```
# Counts = 
0:5
1:5
2:5
3:4
4:4
5:3
#...and so on
```

And I'd prefer that it returned a Series, but it's OK if it's something else. This seems simple enough, but I can't figure it out. I'll post a few failed attempts below.

```
# None of these work
example_series.count(0)
example_series.count(lambda x: x == 0)
example_series[example_series == 0]
example_series.unique()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten the list then use value_counts()

```
pd.Series([item for sublist in example_series for item in sublist]).value_counts()

2     5
1     5
0     5
4     4
3     4
6     3
5     3
11    2
10    2
9     2
8     2
7     2
14    1
13    1
12    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the Pandas syntax is for this. But the pure numpy solution, which would be quite fast, would be to flatten your collection of arrays with np.flatten() and then call the histogram function. This would return a numpy array as a result, which could be wrapped into a Series with one line.